# MySQL 'is after DATE' expression

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a list of recently active customers, based on their last order. The way I've tried it (and expected to work), the results were different than I'd hoped though; Customer__active was 1 for each customer with at least one one attached, whatever the date was...

```
SELECT `Customer`.`id`, `Customer`.`name`, (`DeliveryNote`.`delivery_date` >=2011-05-20) AS `Customer__active`
FROM `customers` AS `Customer`
    LEFT JOIN `delivery_notes` AS `DeliveryNote` ON (`DeliveryNote`.`customer_id` = `Customer`.`id`)
WHERE 1 = 1
GROUP BY `Customer`.`id`
ORDER BY `Customer`.`customerid` ASC
```

Also if anyone has a suggestion regarding the title, please tell me!

Comment: dates should be enclosed in quotes, '2011-05-20'

Comment: Ouch, that just made me feel pretty stupid :')

Comment: Why are you doing 1 = 1? I think the query will work fine even without it. Also there is no need to do the ORDER BY because GROUP BY will give you results order by the grouped field, i.e. `Customer`.`id`. Anyways, I'm not sure if ORDER BY is done on the right field in your query.

Comment: @Abhay, CakePHP just adds 1 = 1. id is the ID used by the system, customerid is used by the company itself (and sometimes has two companies under the same number, which is why it's a seperate field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of a boolean expression is allowed directly like that. You migth want to try something like this:

```
IF(`DeliveryNote`.`delivery_date` >=2011-05-20, 1, 0) AS `Customer__active`
```

Also, instead of sending in the date, you might wanna try DATE(NOW()), because I think that would return "current day", or DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), see here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub

Comment: Actually the boolean expression works, the only problem was the lack of quotes, as said by jishi.

Comment: Well, actually I'm jishi. But you should consider some automatization of the date.

Comment: ... I guess I'm turning blind then. What's the difference between doing it in PHP, and doing it in SQL?

Comment: Thanks for explaining! In this case, the database is running on the same server, and strtotime() apparently is only English based.